# redirect the records to different folder if the format is incorrect using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

i have created the SSIS package to load the comma delimited flat file data into the Sql server destination table.To Achieve this i have used Data flow task, flat file source and ole db destination.I have configured the flat file connection manager with comma separator as a column delimiter and row delimiter as a "CRLF". 
in this case,  package is successfully imported comma separated flat file data into the SQL server destination table.
 Now question is, Do we have any option to send any records with Pipe Delimited to an different folder containing only error records.

Comment: You can redirect failing rows into a flat file, then after the data flow check if the flat file exists and move it to your error folder.

Comment: Why can't you create a flat file in the error folder as a destination into which you redirect bad rows?